# dim(X) must have a positive length when applying function in data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to apply this function to a data frame column:

```
best_recom <- function(x,n=1) {
   y <- result2[x,order(-result2[x,])[n]]
   inds = which(result2[x,] == y, arr.ind=TRUE)
   recom <- names(inds[1])
  return(recom)
}
```

Like this:

```
apply(last_visit[,2], 1, best_recom)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I already tried applying it as a matrix like this:

```
apply(as.matrix(last_visit)[,2],1,recomenda_n_melhor)
```

But I get the same error.
These are the data frames that are used:

result2 - a similarity matrix - this is just a sample

```
          X1.0      X1.1      X2.1      X3.1
X1.0     0.0000000 0.5000000 0.3872983 0.3162278
X1.1     0.5000000 0.0000000 0.2581989 0.0000000
X2.1     0.3872983 0.2581989 0.0000000 0.0000000
X3.1     0.3162278 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

last_visit

```
  customer  cat
1        1 X5.1
2        2 X6.1
3        3 X1.1
4        4 X2.1
```

Comment: Did you check `dim(as.matrix(last_visit)[,2])`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It happens because R coerces `last_visit[,2]` to a dimensionless vector, whereas `apply` expects the object to have some dimensions. You can prevent the coercion by adding `drop=F` to your command, i.e.:

```
apply(last_visit[,2,drop=F], 1, best_recom)
```

Another way would be just to use `lapply` or `sapply` on the vector:

```
lapply(last_visit[,2], best_recom)
```

Comment: No need for `lapply` if it is just one column. Just do `best_recom(last_visit[,2])` surely?

Comment: @thelatemail, I don't think that `best_recom` is properly vectorized

Comment: As @MaratTalipov mentioned, R converts a data frame returned with a single col/row to a vector (by default) which is undesired under some situation; see the post here for a detailed explanation: https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/20/design-flaws-in-r-2-%E2%80%94-dropped-dimensions/#comments